# Loading Images Into TensorFlow2.0 From Local Directory: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm a bit of a TensorFlow newbie, and am working through a tutorial on Neural Style Transfer. To give credit, [The tutorial can be found here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer) and, I'd like to play with it and attempt it with pictures from my local drive, and I believe that's where I'm running afoul.

The Code I'm working on so far is:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
# Load compressed models from tensorflow_hub
os.environ['TFHUB_MODEL_LOAD_FORMAT'] = 'COMPRESSED'
import IPython.display as display

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12,12)
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
import time
import functools

def tensor_to_image(tensor):
  tensor = tensor*255
  tensor = np.array(tensor, dtype=np.uint8)
  if np.ndim(tensor)>3:
    assert tensor.shape[0] == 1
    tensor = tensor[0]
  return PIL.Image.fromarray(tensor)

# Load the content and style images from local directory. 
# This is where I altered the code to use my images
content_path = plt.imread('Content.jpeg')
style_path = plt.imread('Style.jpg')

def load_img(path_to_img):
  max_dim = 512
  img = tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)
  img = tf.image.decode_image(img, channels=3)
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)

  shape = tf.cast(tf.shape(img)[:-1], tf.float32)
  long_dim = max(shape)
  scale = max_dim / long_dim

  new_shape = tf.cast(shape * scale, tf.int32)

  img = tf.image.resize(img, new_shape)
  img = img[tf.newaxis, :]
  return img

def imshow(image, title=None):
  if len(image.shape) > 3:
    image = tf.squeeze(image, axis=0)

  plt.imshow(image)
  if title:
    plt.title(title)

content_image = load_img(content_path)
style_image = load_img(style_path)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
imshow(content_image, 'Content Image')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
imshow(style_image, 'Style Image')
```

At which point I get an error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-422fe51b5fbe> in <module>
----> 1 content_image = load_img(content_path)
      2 style_image = load_img(style_path)
      3 
      4 plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
      5 imshow(content_image, 'Content Image')

<ipython-input-43-3717b62ca1b6> in load_img(path_to_img)
      1 def load_img(path_to_img):
      2   max_dim = 512
----> 3   img = tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)
      4   img = tf.image.decode_image(img, channels=3)
      5   img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py in read_file(filename, name)
    550   if tld.is_eager:
    551     try:
--> 552       _result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
    553         _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "ReadFile", name,
    554         tld.op_callbacks, filename)

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

I think I realized now that the `load_img(path_to_img)` function is not jiving with the actual jpeg's I've loaded in, which unlike in the tutorial is just the path. The original which works fine is:

```
content_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg')
style_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('kandinsky5.jpg','https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/Vassily_Kandinsky%2C_1913_-_Composition_7.jpg')
```

Checking the data type `type(content_path)` is `str`

However what I've changed to retrieve files from my local machine:

```
content_path = plt.imread('Content.jpeg')
style_path = plt.imread('Style.jpg')
```

and checking the data type `type(content_path)` is `numpy.ndarray`

I'm guessing I will either need to change how I load in the data or change the function to make it compatible to preprocess the jpeg images.

How should I go about doing that and what should I change if I want to just load and use images from my local directory?

**Edit**

So, I think that loading in the individual images the way I did is fine, but it's just needing to adjust the function. I'm not sure why I'm getting that error message.

```
# Load the content and style images
content = plt.imread('Content.jpeg')
style = plt.imread('Style.jpg')


def transform_img(raw_img):
  max_dim = 512
  #img = tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)
  img = tf.image.decode_image(raw_img, channels=3)
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)

  shape = tf.cast(tf.shape(img)[:-1], tf.float32)
  long_dim = max(shape)
  scale = max_dim / long_dim

  new_shape = tf.cast(shape * scale, tf.int32)

  img = tf.image.resize(img, new_shape)
  img = img[tf.newaxis, :]
  return img
  
def imshow(image, title=None):
  if len(image.shape) > 3:
    image = tf.squeeze(image, axis=0)

  plt.imshow(image)
  if title:
    plt.title(title)

content_image = transform_img(content)
style_image = transform_img(style)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
imshow(content_image, 'Content Image')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
imshow(style_image, 'Style Image')
```

And I'm just wondering how to resolve the bellow error that occurs after the last line above.

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

Answer (score 0):

The plt.imread returns pixel data of the image as a numpy array. [Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html)

While the method tf.io.read_file in load_img seems to want a physical path to the file on your computer, similar to the tutorial you linked. This is where the ValueError is stemming from. [read_file Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/read_file)

My suggestion is to use the tf.keras.utils.get_file method as in the tutorial, set that to content_path, and then try the load_img method. [get_file Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_file)

```
content_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('[PATH TO Content.jpg]')
style_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('[PATH TO Style.jpg]')
```

You will have to handle plotting with a separate variable. Hope this helped! New to answering questions on Stack so let me know if I can help further!

Comment: My impression was that the get_file method was for web data. I attempted nonetheless, but got an error "Exception: URL fetch failure on [C: Path To picture.jpeg]: None -- unknown url type: c" with C being the of the path form my C drive.

Comment: I think you are right, did you try setting the path variables to a string with the file path?